# Resolve my domain with a CDN IP

Tags: dns, cdn

I'm not a routing expert. But what I know: It can be a really big topic. So, I'm currently thinking about geo-load balancing and how I can provide it. You can use Route 53 to create GeoDNS lookups. And this is fine and good. But I think about CDNs. I have only two location, while CDNs have tons of locations. Why not resolving my domain www.example.com with one of these CDNs IPs directly? My frontend is static. The dynamic stuff is created by Javascript. So, is it possible to resolve my domain example.com directly with the nearest CDN IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is quite usual setup. On AWS, after you create CloudFront distribution, you will simply create ALIAS in your Route53 console:

```
www.example.com A ALIAS xyz123xyz.cloudfront.net
```

If you are using other CDN/DNS providers, you will create CNAME record:

```
www.example.com CNAME xyz456xyz.somecdn.net
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I know that you can do this. Correct me, if I'm wrong: With this solution, the client resolves first the domain www.example.com with xyz123xyz.cloudfront.net. And then, the client need another lookup for xyz123xyz.cloudfront.net. Why not creating an A record in example.com with an IP-Adresse of the CDN server?

Comment: Usually, there is no "an" IP address of CDN server, because there is way more than one server, on many different locations (that is the whole purpose of CDN, to be as close to the client as possible). If you google for random Cloudfront.net dns name, and try to get its IP address as seen from different parts of the world [here](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/d15gt9gwxw5wu0.cloudfront.net) you will see the huge number of different addresses.

Comment: And even if you'd want to add all those addresses to your geoDNS zone, it will be wrong since addresses of CDN servers that are serving your content can change (often) in the future.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But my question is: Why resolving a name with another name and then with an IP. Why not directly resolving the first name with an IP Adresse. More steps also mean increasing the latency. So, is it possible to configure the CDN to interpret my domain as the same as xyz123xyz.cloudfront.net. So that the CDN writes the correct, and location based IPs, to A record to my domain.

Comment: Well, actually AWS CloudFront will do exactly that for you if configured as above. But in general case, where DNS and CDN are not under same authority, it would probably not make much sense (both for you to allow CDN to have control over your domain, or for CDN to continuously update DNS of thousands of their customers). Anyway, DNS responses are cached and the latency that you mention will only happen on the very first request.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to resolve your domain to only one CDN IP. And when we talk about CDN IP, it is usually virtual IP (Anycast IP) where it maps to different physical edge servers globally. Depending on where the request is coming from, that virtual IP will map to the edge server closest to the end user.

Take this domain www.cloudflare.com for example, it is on Cloudflare (http://www.whatsmycdn.com/?uri=www.cloudflare.com), and it is pointing to two Cloudflare virtual IPs for failover purpose I suppose.

```
dig www.cloudflare.com +short
198.41.215.162
198.41.214.162
```

Of course, pointing that domain to only one Cloudflare virtual IP is completely doable, although it is not desireable.